# "DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in" in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

What is the equivalent of the Swift code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.detectObjects()
    }
```

In Objective C?

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // use weakSelf here
});
```